# Spring Boot @ControllerAdvice exception handler not firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I had the following controller advice set up, to return an APIs contract for error conditions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler()
{
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable::class)
    @ResponseBody
    public fun onException(ex: Throwable): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>
    {
        val errorResponse = ErrorResponse(
           response = ResponseHeader(ex.responseCode(), ex.message))
        return ResponseEntity(errorResponse, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

It *was* working fine and then stopped working. Now all exceptions are routed to `BasicErrorController`, which returns the following format:

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1450495303166,
  "status" : 403,
  "error" : "Forbidden",
  "message" : "Access Denied",
  "path" : "/profile/candidates"
}
```

The above is a nice opinionated starting point, but now it won't get out of the way.

- I've tried replacing the error handlers with one instance of `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` but that didn't work.
- I've tried making my own CustomErrorHandler, but that also wasn't suitable since the original exception is no longer in the `HttpServletRequest` by the time it re-routes to the custom error controller. This information is needed in order to return an appropriate response to the client.

**How to I:**

- Make SpringBoot *not* forward exceptions to an exception controller.
- Restore @ControllerAdvice exception handlers, so that I can just return an appropriate response body and status code.

On startup spring logs:

```
main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionHandler
main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in responseEntityExceptionHandler
```

**Edit:**

After reading through the Spring Boot docs, I under stand now that the BasicErrorController is only supposed to fire for any exceptions *not* handled by a `@ControllerAdvice`. This appears not to be happening. So the question is why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also have a Spring Security filter that evaluates API-Key and Access-Token header credentials. @ControllerAdvice doesn't work here - fair enough, given we're not dealing with a controller endpoint!

Use EntryPoint and AcessDeniedHandler to handle exceptions from security filters. There are can be configured inside:

```
.exceptionHandling()
```

And configure FailureHandler if you extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter in your filter.

```
 setAuthenticationFailureHandler()
```

Afaik ErrorController will be overwritten if you will deploy your application under application server.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't follow. Ended up using the approach in my answer. Not sure if it is a good one.